# UVC camera is being turned on at random moments

Tags: webcam, uvc

Just bought an A4TECH PK-1000HA webcam and it's being turned on (backlight turned on) at the system's bootup/shutdown and sometimes at random moments when I surf the web via Chrome for instance.

Is it righteous behavior and/or could I ask my webcam to turn on only when needed (e.g. on Zoom-meetings)?

*Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS*

Comment: If the webcam has been designed by the manufacturer to turn on it's light briefly when powered on and probed by the OS, then yes that might indeed be correct (but unwanted) behavior.

Comment: @user535733 On Windows OS it's just a bit of a second that the webcam turns on/off (and it's only at shutdown).